# Read Mac Touch ID In Mathematica

Tags: mac-os-x, system

Apple seems to provide some support for developers to authenticate users biometrically with the touch id sensor in the form of a swift API
[(see here)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication/). I'm wondering if there is an easy way to do this directly from Mathematica?

In the end, I want to make a simple Mathematica app that will decrypt data only when the touch ID sensor is accepted.

What I've tried is using a call to [touch ID sensor library](https://github.com/lukaskollmer/python-touch-id/blob/master/touchid.py) written in python as an external process. This doesn't seem like a very elegant solution and since I know Mathematica provides native support for accessing many hardware features (microphone, camera, IO on Raspberry PI) I'm wondering if there's a clean native way to implement this.

Thanks

Comment: I think that a nicer alternative to a single line sending people to follow a link and read about the issue *you* care about, would be to explain what is available on the link, how have you tried to implement it on mathematical, and highlighting anything similar you have seen already implemented in Wolfram Language. Where is your code?

Comment: @rhermans thanks for the suggestion, I've elaborated my original post